# Why does Pycharm highlight a warning over this assert statement?

Tags: python-2.7, pycharm

I have the following assert statement written for code that I am still in the process of testing to make sure the number n is close enough to 1.

```
assert (-.001 < 1 - n < .001)
```

PyCharm highlights the .001 with a warning that says 'expected type int but got float'.  I would like to know how this statement can be rewritten to avoid this warning, or if there is a way for PyCharm to ignore these types of warnings.  Also, why is .001 highlighted, but not -.001?

Comment: Are you using the open source version? It would be interesting to go through their syntax highlighter module and figure out what they're upto.

Comment: Yes, I've looked through the inspection configurations but can't figure out what specific rule is causing this code to highlight.

Comment: Please file an issue here https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/PY

Comment: This is a known bug in PyCharm. [Track it here](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-23367).